# How to write React hooks with called functions?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useQuery() hook:

```
const useQuery = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const build = (query) => {}
  const read = () => {}
}
export default useQuery;
```

I want to be able to use hook in my code like:

```
const query = useQuery();

useEffect(()=>{
  const oldQuery = query.read();
  if(oldQuery.length === 0) query.build(newQuery);
},[])
```

but every time I try to call `query.read()` I get error `Property 'read' does not exist on type 'void'.` It looks like scope issue. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a return statement in `useQuery`:

```
const useQuery = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const build = (query) => {}
  const read = () => {}

  return { router, build, read }
}
```

You may also want to consider memoizing these functions, so that code which consumes this hook doesn't do unnecessary work because it thinks the functions have changed:

```
const build = useCallback((query) => {}, []);
const read = useCallback((() => {}, []);
```